# How to enter a new entry to a API server using requests.post?

Tags: python, python-requests, webapi, web-api-testing

[This is the question from the course I am following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7wo3.png)

I am getting an error while trying to put the required details by using requests.post. When I am using request.post the wesite should be uploaded with the details i am posting right? But it does not show anything that i am uploading.

```
import requests
BASE_URL = 'http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080'
product_entity = {"products":{"product": {"productName": "Araliya Basmathi Rice", "description":"White Basmathi Rice imported from Pakistan. High-quality rice with extra fragrance. Organically grown.", "category": "Rice",  "brand": "CIC" , "expiredDate": "2023.02.04", "manufacturedDate": "2022.002.20", "batchNumber": "324567", "unitPrice": "1020", "quantity": "200", "createdDate": "2022.02.24"  }}}
response = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}/products", json=product_entity)
print(response.status_code)
#print(response.json())
```

This is my code. But it does not result the details being uploaded to the website. Can anyone help me with understanding the error please?

[This is the error message I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atz3C.png)

Comment: What's the status code of the response? If it's a 403, it means that the request was forbidden.

Comment: It gives 404. 
This is the address I have used. http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080/

Comment: 404 the endpoint is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status code respond that I was getting was 404. Which is the endpoint not found.
In the question, the endpoint that should be used is given as `/api/products/` for `requests.post` .

This is the modified code.

```
import requests
BASE_URL = 'http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080'
product_entity = {"products":{"product": {"productName": "Araliya Basmathi Rice", "description":"White Basmathi Rice imported from Pakistan. High-quality rice with extra fragrance. Organically grown.", "category": "Rice",  "brand": "CIC" , "expiredDate": "2023.02.04", "manufacturedDate": "2022.002.20", "batchNumber": "324567", "unitPrice": "1020", "quantity": "200", "createdDate": "2022.02.24"  }}}
response = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}/api/products", json=product_entity)
print(response.status_code)
#print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

A 404 means that the URL endpoint which you're trying to access cannot be found. Check again if the endpoint you're trying to access (which is just the root of the website `/`) accepts a POST request.

Maybe there's another endpoint which accepts the post request (for example `/create/`)

Comment: I still get 404. I used `response = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}/create/", json=product_entity)`

Comment: First you need to verify if the `/create/` endpoint exists and then check if it accepts POST requests

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the endpoint that I am supposed to use and it was `/api/products/` rather than `/` . Thank you for your help.